# SnowflakeとMicrosoft ACCESSの接続方法について

Tags: ms-access

Microsoft ACCESSのODBC設定について伺いたいです。
SnowflakeテーブルをODBC接続でACCESSに連携できるようにしたいです。
その連携方法は「リンクテーブルを作成してソースデータにリンクする」にしています。
その上で、Snowflakeのユーザーやロールなど必要な情報を入力して接続認証はできたものの、ACCESSファイルを閉じて開く度にそれらの認証情報の入力を求められてしまいます。
開く度に求められないように設定は可能でしょうか？
その方法をご教示いただきたいです。